# Full URLs in Rails logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, dns, hostname

Is it possible to get the full URLs in the logs of a Rails application? Currently I'm getting something like:

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-27 13:13:10 +0200

but I need to get:

> Started GET "http://localhost:3000/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-27 13:13:10 +0200

because this is an app where the domains are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Rails 3.2.12, instead of monkey-patching before_dispatch or call_app, there is now a method that receives the request and returns the `Started GET "/session/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-26 14:51:42 -0700` bit.

So you can instead override that method in your own logger or monkey patch just that method.

```
# or "class Rails::Rack::Logger < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber" for monkey patch
class URLLogger < Rails::Rack::Logger 

  def started_request_message(request)
    'Started %s "%s%s%s" for %s at %s' % [
      request.request_method,
      request.protocol,
      request.host_with_port,
      request.filtered_path,
      request.ip,
      Time.now.to_default_s ]
  end
end
```

If you subclass don't forget to modify the middleware chain in `config/application.rb` (and make sure URLLogger is loaded before the configuration block):

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, URLLogger)
config.middleware.delete(Rails::Rack::Logger)
```

Answer (score 6):

The line is coming from the middleware [`Rails::Rack::Logger`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb), which is in railties.  At the simplest, you could just override the method doing the logging, e.g., in an initializer:

```
class Rails::Rack::Logger < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
  protected

  def before_dispatch(env)
    request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
    info "\n\nStarted #{request.request_method} \"#{request.url}\" for #{request.ip} at #{Time.now.to_default_s}"
  end
end
```

If you'd rather not override the logger, you could always add your own, which you've already created, then delete `Rails::Rack::Logger` from the stack via:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, YourLogger)
config.middleware.delete(Rails::Rack::Logger)
```

If you go this route you might check out the rack logger for its usage of `ActionDispatch::Request`, and be sure to do the other job it does of flushing the log subscriber cache after dispatch, via `ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber.flush_all!`

Comment: I applied this snippet to my rails project, and it works well in my development env, but not in production env. Still not know why

Comment: Just guessing but is your production log level above `info`? Its worth noting also that this answer is no longer current. The rack logger has changed since.

Comment: If you replace before_dispatch with call_app it will work in Rails 3.2.x

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this without changing Rails itself, which isn't nice, but you can add your own log call:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :log_request

  protected

  def log_request
    logger.info("Started #{request.method} #{request.url}")
  end    

end
```

Comment: The only drawbacks I see to this solution is that the custom log line is not next to the main one and it won't log for images, javascript, etc. I'm not sure if the latter would be a problem later on in the project which it's more complex.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I'm using for now was creating this class:

```
class HostnameLogger
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    uri = env["REQUEST_URI"]
    if uri.blank? # While testing a Rails app, there's no env["REQUEST_UIR"] defined.
      uri = "http://#{env["HTTP_HOST"]}#{env["PATH_INFO"]}"
    end
    Rails.logger.info "Started #{env["REQUEST_METHOD"]} \"#{uri}\" for #{env["REMOTE_ADDR"]} at #{Time.now}"
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

and then adding it as Rack middleware (in application.rb):

```
config.middleware.use "HostnameLogger"
```

so I get:

> Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-27 15:33:40 +0200
>
> Started GET "http://localhost:3000/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-27 15:33:40 +0200

Answer (score 1):

```
Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
  protected
  def started_request_message(request)
    "Started #{request.request_method} \"#{request.url}\" for #{request.ip} at #{Time.now.to_default_s}"
  end
end
```